# > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android-studio

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnpUu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BGEg.png)

why this problem shows to me sdk location in sdk manager and in sdk location file is same .how i can resolve this

sdk.dir=C:\Users\mrabh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
i have changed this format to this

sdk.dir=C:\Users\mrabh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk